# 3 combobox box,change one by one,each select the first item auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-easyui

I have 3 comboboxes,when i select the first combobox,i want the first item of the second combobox and third combobox been selected auto.
when the first item of second combobox been selected,will trigger the onselect event of the third combobox,but the parameter `record` is undefined

```
$("#c2").combobox({
            onSelect:function(record)
```

when i select an item of the first combobox ,the `record` here is  undefined.
when i select an item of  the second combobox,it is not

why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/color.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //simulate the database
    var data={};
    data.id1=[{value:"id1",text:"aa1"},{value:"id2",text:"aa2"}];
    data.id2=[{value:"id3",text:"aa3"},{value:"id4",text:"aa4"}];
    data.id1.id1=[{value:"id1",text:"aaa1"},{value:"id2",text:"aaa2"}];
    data.id1.id2=[{value:"id3",text:"aaa3"},{value:"id4",text:"aaa4"}];
    data.id2.id1=[{value:"id5",text:"aaa5"},{value:"id6",text:"aaa6"}];
    data.id2.id2=[{value:"id7",text:"aaa7"},{value:"id8",text:"aaa8"}];
    $(function(){
        var c1id;
        $("#c1").combobox("loadData",[{value:"id1",text:"a1"},{value:"id2",text:"a2"}]);
        //change c2 box when c1 on select
        $("#c1").combobox({
            onSelect:function(record){
                c1id=record.value;
                $("#c2").combobox("clear");
                $("#c2").combobox("loadData",data[record.value]);
                try{var c2data=$("#c2").combobox("getData");//c2data.length is 0?
                value=c2data[0].text;
                $("#c2").combobox("select",value);}
                catch(e){

                }
            }
        }) 
        $("#c2").combobox({
            onSelect:function(record){
                $("#c3").combobox("clear");
                $("#c3").combobox("loadData",data[c1id][record.value]);
                try{var c2data=$("#c3").combobox("getData");//c2data.length is 0?
                value=c2data[0].text;
                $("#c3").combobox("select",value);}
                catch(e){

                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="c1" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c2" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c3" class="easyui-combobox">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the value of a combobox, you should pass a *value*, not a *text*, by which I mean

```
value=c2data[0].text;
$("#c2").combobox("select",value);}
```

should be

```
value=c2data[0].value;
$("#c2").combobox("select",value);}
```

If you *select* an nonexistent value, the combobox does displays it, but not associate it with an object. That is why you get a `undefined`.